# Breaking on your own exceptions in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, exception, intellij-idea, breakpoints

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934794/is-there-break-on-exception-in-intellij) on how to break on any exceptions.

I'm getting a million exceptions on startup. I've tried ignoring ClassNotFoundException, but it's no good, the IDE still seems to break on these (and other) exceptions.

So .. what's a decent configuration for this to catch only real exceptions caught from user code? (Ignore also any exception in jUnit, if applicable)

Comment: Didn't understand clearly. Why can't you add the user exception class itself as breakpoint?

Comment: I added it, but it didn't quite work - IntelliJ still didn't break on this exception (at least in some cases).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by the other posters, **Class Filters** are the way to do this.

Specifically, you could add the package names for what you consider "your code" as a class filter.  The syntax is a little opaque, but using a simple wildcard filter like:

> com.whatever.package.*

sounds like it it will work for you.  IntelliJ will break on any exception in any class in any package under here.  You can of course define multiple wildcard filters if your code is in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

I was just messing with this earlier.  Two ways to go:

1) Configure it to explicitly catch your exception, not "any exception" - if it's something like RuntimeException, this may not be filter-y enough. 
2) Use the class results filter - this for whatever reason did NOT work for me.  Ever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer because I had a hard time finding the Class Filters sub-dialog mentioned in *serg10*'s accepted answer.  To see that sub-dialog do the following:

1) Open the View Breakpoints dialog using the following keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + F8), assuming you have not changed the binding for that shortcut.

2) Check the entry in the left hand column titled" "Java Exception Breakpoints".  That should automatically check the child item titled "Any Exception" belonging to that top level element.

3) **Click directly on the child item titled "Any exception".** You should now see the Class filters drop-down box on the right hand side.

4) Check the check-box next "Class Filters".  The *View Breakpoints* dialog should now look like this:

[image]

5) Click on the ellipsis next to the *Class Filters* drop-down box.  You should now see the *Class Filters* dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked IJ and I see tons of options. Maybe the class filters is your option?

Comment: Nice.  This tip got me to what I needed.  Creating an exception FILTER was too large.  Being able to switch on/off specific exception classes is what I needed.  I've been using IntelliJ for 10 years.  Never done this before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [these instructions to create a specific exception breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-exception-breakpoints.html). In short:

1. On the main menu, choose Run | View Breakpoints, or press ⇧⌘F8.
2. In the Breakpoints dialog box that opens, click add.
3. Select Exception Breakpoints from the drop-down list.
   [image]
   <sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/idea/create_exception_breakpoint.png))</sub>
4. In the Select Exception Class dialog box, specify the desired exception class from the library, or from the project, and click OK.