# IntelliJ IDEA - Show Exception Traces

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, stack-trace

I found a bit of help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934794/is-there-break-on-exception-in-intellij), but nothing substantial.

I've successfully moved my Android project from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA, and am trying to get used to the UI. I've set it up to build and run, but when I throw an exception, I can't figure out how to view the stack trace like Eclipse presents it.

For example, running this in Eclipse:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar)).setText("Temp");
```

Yields the following, in Eclipse's "LogCat" View:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appname/com.appname.activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.appname.activity.HomeActivity.init(HomeActivity.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.appname.activity.HomeActivity.access$0(HomeActivity.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.appname.activity.HomeActivity$1.execute(HomeActivity.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.appname.helper.Security.checkCredentialsAndLogin(Security.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.appname.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:118)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
```

Whereas in IntelliJ I just get something that looks like this, when I "Debug ProjectName", after enabling "Break on all Exceptions":

[image]

Comment: What do you see in log console? You will see exception there

Comment: Don't you see your exception in the Console tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a separate [Android Logcat tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-tool-window.html#d9052e1147), exceptions are logged there. If you are targeting 4.1 Platform, make sure to use IDEA 11.1.3 which provides compatibility for the recent changes in Logcat.

Comment: I'm able to find this window, however it does not display Exceptions, E/. How do i configure it? I have IDEA 11.1.3.

Comment: Found it. Its Run -> View Breakpoints -> Log message to console